# Grid geometry manager won't center the frame in the middle of the window

Tags: python, tkinter

I started to develop some GUIs in python not long ago, and I finally decided I know enough to write a full GUI with the grid geometry manager.
**I was surprised to see that when I try to extend the frame of the grid to the window edges using the `sticky="nsew"` argument, it did not work and all the elements in the grid remained in the top left corner of the screen.**

You can check my code and some screenshots of it below.

To fix the issue, I have tried various solutions, including removing the `sticky` argument (line 7), however, this messes up the background color and the frame doesn't extend to the window edges.
How can I fix this issue and make the frame extend to the window borders? Thanks in advance! (;

Using the `GridPage` class - **not centerd!**
[image: placed using grid]

using the `PackPage` class and the `.pack()` function - **centerd like I need**
[image: placed using grid]

Here is my code for the second example:

```py
import tkinter as tk

class DefaultPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")


class GridPage(DefaultPage):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        DefaultPage.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Button(self, text='hello!').grid()
        tk.Label(self, text="I'm placed USING GRID").grid()


class PackPage(DefaultPage):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        DefaultPage.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Button(self, text='hi there!').pack()
        tk.Label(self, text="I'm placed USING PACK").pack()


root = tk.Tk()

baseframe = tk.Frame(root)
baseframe.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
baseframe.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
baseframe.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

# frame = PackPage(baseframe, bg='yellow')  # second screenshot. works as intended
frame = GridPage(baseframe, bg='yellow')  # not centerd in the middle of the window.

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure the weights for rows and columns.
By default, the weights = 0, which means the widget within the frame will always shrink to the least possible size. So you need to configure that.

This is achieved using these functions
`grid_rowconfigure()` and  `grid_columnconfigure()`

What you need to do here as it seems is to make the column weight = 1 to expand with the container while keeping the 1st row's weight = 0 to make your label and button always stick up.

Your code will be like this

```
class DefaultPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=0)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)


class GridPage(DefaultPage):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        DefaultPage.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Button(self, text='hello!').grid(sticky="n")
        tk.Label(self, text="I'm placed USING GRID").grid(sticky="n")
```

Comment: Thank you! works perfectly. Wouldn't be able to do this without you (;

Comment: glad to be of help :)